# PHPExcel gera planilha quebrada

Tags: php, microsoft-excel, phpexcel

Estou usando a class PHPExcel para exportar uma tabela do BD.
Porem estou tendo problemas no download da planilha.
Para testar, inserir valores manualmente sem fazer nenhum select no BD.
Porem quando ele gera a planilha e faz o download, a planilha abre quebrada.

CONTROLLER:

```
    <?php
require "models/class.exportacaomodel.php";

  class ExportacaoController extends Controller{

function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
}


 public function listarCampos(){
    $ExportacaoModel = new ExportacaoModel();
    $retorno    = $ExportacaoModel -> listarCamposPersonalizadosContato();        
    $this -> view -> retorno = $retorno;
    $this -> view -> setView("viewsTest/exportacao/exportacao");
}

public function exportar(){

  $nome = $_POST['nome'];
  $sobrenome = $_POST['sobrenome'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $dataNascimento = $_POST['dataNascimento'];
  $camposPersonalizados = $_POST['campos_personalizados'];     


  $ExportacaoModel = new ExportacaoModel();
  $retorno    = $ExportacaoModel -> exportar();        
  $this -> view -> retorno = $retorno;
  $this -> view -> setView("viewsTest/exportacao/passo_2");
}


 }

    ?>
```

MODEL:

```
<?php  

  require_once "/util/exportacao/PHPExcel_1.7.9/Classes/PHPExcel.php";

  class ExportacaoModel extends Model{

    function __construct(){
      parent::__construct();
    }


public function listarCamposPersonalizadosContato(){

    $stmt = $this -> db -> prepare("SELECT  id, nome, tipo_personalizado  FROM tblrlzcampospersonalizadoscontato WHERE tipo_formulario = 'contato' ");
    $stmt->execute();
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $rows;

}

public function exportar(){

    $query_str  = "SELECT DISTINCT ass.IdAssinante, ass.Nome, ass.Email FROM tblrlzassinante AS ass";
    $query_str .= " INNER JOIN tblrlzassinanteareadeinteresse AS aai ON aai.IdAssinante = ass.IdAssinante";   
    $query_str .= " INNER JOIN tblrlzvalorescampospersonalizadoscontato AS cpc ON cpc.id_contato = ass.IdAssinante";

    $stmt = $this -> db -> prepare($query_str);
    $stmt -> execute();
    $rows = $stmt -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    // Create new PHPExcel object
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

    // Set document properties
    $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Teste")
                                 ->setLastModifiedBy("Teste")
                                 ->setTitle("Relatorio")
                                 ->setSubject("Relatorio")
                                 ->setDescription("Relatorio.")
                                 ->setKeywords("relatorio ")
                                 ->setCategory("arquivo relatorio");


    // Add some data
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 'Id');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B1', 'Nome');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C1', 'Email');  

    $linha = 2;
    foreach ( $rows as $item => $contato) { 
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$linha, $contato["IdAssinante"] ); //var_dump( $contato["IdAssinante"] );
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$linha, $contato["Nome"] ); //var_dump( $contato["Nome"] );
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.$linha, $contato["Email"] );   var_dump( $contato["Email"] );           
    }

    // Set column widths
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(20);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth(50);   
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('C')->setWidth(100);          

    //Set bold
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->getFont()->setBold(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B1')->getFont()->setBold(true);  
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C1')->getFont()->setBold(true); 

    // Rename worksheet
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Simple');

    // Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

    $arquivo = date("Y-m-d-H-i-s")."-".rand(1, 9999).".xls";
    // Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel5)
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$arquivo.'"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    // If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

    // If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
    header ('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
    header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT'); // always modified
    header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
    header ('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
    exit;

}

  }

 ?>
```

Como a planilha fica depois do download:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Fiquei sem entender qual framework é este. É codeigniter?

Comment: Não estou usando nenhum framework. MVC puro.

Comment: mvc não é uma tecnologia é uma padrão de projeto, quando você usa `class ExportacaoModel extends Model` a sua classe é estendida de outra classe, uma classe padrão que provavelmente faz parte de algum framework, mesmo que tenha sido você que criou o tal framework, se não informar isto será um pouco dificil reproduzir o problema pra encontrar a origem da falha.

Comment: Vou tentar usar a parte do PDO e ver se o problema ocorre. Talvez não seja no teu Model.

Comment: Editei a resposta, veja ela por favor.

Comment: O `utf8_decode` resolveu o problema?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento o utf8_code nao resolveu o meu problema.

Comment: Desculpe a sinceridade mas pela sua resposta, jogar no `php://output` não funcionou porque você provavelmente deve ter mais código que não foi mencionado na pergunta, talvez seja algo em `viewsTest/exportacao/passo_2`, ainda sim é um problema que não poderia ser resolvido e apenas um redirecionamento para contornar o bug, mas não corrigi-lo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi o problema da seguinte forma:

Em vez de baixar a planilha diretamente. Eu salvo ela no servidor, e depois baixo.

Comentei o header, e fiz as seguintes alterações:

```
 $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
    //$objWriter->save('php://output');
    //exit;

    $objWriter->save(UPLOAD_ABSPATH.$arquivo);

    header("Location:".HOME_URI."/viewsTest/_uploads/".$arquivo);
```

Assim, a planilha é baixada normal, sem quebras.

Answer (score 4):

Após testar o código que postou atualizado, notei que o problema ocorreu no *Office2007* também, então notei este trecho:

```
$linha = 2;
foreach ( $rows as $item => $contato) { 
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$linha, $contato["IdAssinante"] ); //var_dump( $contato["IdAssinante"] );
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$linha, $contato["Nome"] ); //var_dump( $contato["Nome"] );
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.$linha, $contato["Email"] );   var_dump( $contato["Email"] );           
}
```

Note que tem um `var_dump( $contato["Email"] );` não comentado, foi um erro de digitação seu, se você fizer isto ele irá funcionar:

```
$linha = 2;
foreach ( $rows as $item => $contato) { 
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$linha, $contato["IdAssinante"] );
    //var_dump( $contato["IdAssinante"] );
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$linha, $contato["Nome"] );
    //var_dump( $contato["Nome"] );
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.$linha, $contato["Email"] );
    //var_dump( $contato["Email"] );           
}
```

O problema também pode ser o utf8, então você pode usar o `utf8_decode`:

```
$linha = 2;
foreach ( $rows as $item => $contato) { 
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$linha, utf8_decode($contato["IdAssinante"]) );
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$linha, utf8_decode($contato["Nome"]) );
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.$linha, utf8_decode($contato["Email"]) );        
}
```

<s>Testei o seu código e funcionou perfeitamente usando *Microsoft Office 2007*. Pelas imagens que postou você esta usado o *BrOffice* foi estinto e a sua ultima versão liberada foi a *3.3.2* (22 de março de 2011; há 4 anos)</s>

### Como foi o processo

<sub>Fonte: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/BrOffice</sub>

Em 17 de março de 2011, foi decidida, em uma reunião no Rio de Janeiro, a extinção da Associação BrOffice.org por unanimidade dos votos dos membros presentes, encerrando as atividades sociais em 30 de abril de 2011 e cumprindo com todas as obrigações legais até o dia 16 de maio de 2011. Todo o patrimônio da Associação BrOffice.org, sendo apenas bens móveis e recursos financeiros em contas vinculadas ao CNPJ da Associação, foi revertido a entidades que promovem o software livre, com autorização de uma doação à comunidade do Debian Brasil e o pagamento do serviço de tradução da documentação do PostgreSQL 8.4. Foi sugerido por Cláudio Ferreira Filho, em nota publicada no site do BrOffice.org sobre a extinção, que o momento da extinção da Associação era também o momento para um alinhamento dos esforços da comunidade brasileira com o projeto internacional LibreOffice, incluindo a substituição do nome no Brasil para LibreOffice. Desde então, a comunidade brasileira trabalhou em diversas atividades de documentação para a mudança efetiva do nome BrOffice para LibreOffice e nas necessidades da transferência do conteúdo presente no site oficial do projeto brasileiro BrOffice para uma versão em português brasileiro do site do LibreOffice. A versão 3.4, posterior à versão 3.3.2, já apresentava o nome LibreOffice para a versão em português brasileiro.

### Baixar o LibreOffice

Segue o link para download https://pt-br.libreoffice.org

### Conclusão

O problema não é com o *PHPExcel* e sim que você esta usando um software muito desatualizado e que não tem mais suporte, sendo agora o seu sucesso o *LibreOffice*.

Comment: To usando esse mesmo código em outro sistema, e a unica diferença é que o outro esta carregando as linhas de uma tabela do MySql. E quando clico pra baixar, ele baixa normal, sem essa quebra.  Ai quando fiz o carregamento das linhas manualmente, a planilha fica quebrada.
Ja tentei também exportar para a planilha do google, e ela continua quebrada.

Comment: É como eu disse @BrunoDM você esta usando uma versão de um office que não recebe mais atualizações e provavelmente alguma feature que foi adicionada ao XLS gerado não é suportada por ele (é apenas uma teoria), como eu disse para mim seu código funcionou perfeitamente no *office2007*. Se você instalar o libreoffice e o problema ocorrer nele também então poderemos presumir que o problema é no phpexcel, caso contrário tudo leva a crer que o problema é no broffice. Não importa muito o outro sistema, mas sim qual office você usou no outro sistema. Uma duvida, qual versão do php usou?

Comment: Acabei de fazer um teste aqui. E criei uma pagina PHP fora da estrutura MVC, e a planilha é gerada normal, sem nenhuma quebra, abre sem nenhum problema no BrOffice.  Ai quando eu coloco o mesmo código dentro da função do model, ele gera a planilha quebrada. Ele pode ficar dentro da função do model ? Ou tem que ter uma pagina PHP só pra ele ?  To usando a versão 5.3.6 do PHP.

Comment: @BrunoDM não tenho como afirmar, isto que comentou agora invalida toda a minha resposta, este tipo de informação tem que ser colocada na pergunta, espero que entenda isto como uma critica construtiva. Poste um código que "gere o problema" dentro do corpo da sua pergunta (edite a pergunta para isto). Então poderei testar.

Comment: coloquei todo o código do Controller e Model. Muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Eu ja tinha testado sem aquele var_dump. E continua quebrado. Coloquei o var_dumo só pra conferir se o select estava trazendo certo. E com o var_dum sem estar comentado, a planilha fica assim aqui: http://i.imgur.com/lWj7P80.jpg

Comment: @BrunoDM Acho que entendi, parece um problema com utf8, editei a resposta tente o utf8_decode.